# Can't open serial monitor while pyserial script is working, using nodemcu

Tags: python, python-3.x, esp8266, pyserial, nodemcu

I have a program which constantly sends data from Pyton to NodeMCU esp8266 (connected to the computer with a micro usb cable) using PySerial library. The program works without a problem on a mac computer but gives error on Windows computer.

Commented line is for mac, the line below is for windows.

```
if connect:
    #arduino = serial.Serial(port='/dev/cu.usbserial-10', baudrate=9600, timeout=.1)
    arduino = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600, timeout=.1)
    print("arduino bağlandı")
```

Using python, I edit data and send it constantly to the NodeMCU, the code below is in a while loop

```
           if connected:
                arduino.write(bytes(some_string, 'utf-8'))
                print(msj, "sent")
                time.sleep(0.1)
```

I've attached servo's to the NodeMCU and turn them according to the data I get from Python program.

```
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {

    int x = Serial.read();
```

Later I use this x value according to my needs.

As I mentioned, the program works fine on a mac computer. However on a windows computer, I can't run both programs at the same time. If I start the python program, I get "Port monitor error: command 'open' failed: Serial port busy. Could not connect to COM5 serial port." error when I try to open the serial monitor on arduino IDE.

I've tried running the NodeMCU first but then I couldn't run the Python program.

Comment: That's just the way serial ports work; you can't open one from more than one program at the same time.  Perhaps you can find some sort of low-level serial port monitor program, that can coexist with your Python program - I would suggest Microsoft's Portmon, but I don't think it still works on modern systems.